# Getting Coordinates from Selenium IDE

Tags: html, firefox, user-interface, selenium, selenium-ide

I am trying to work with the Selenium IDE on Firefox. I was wondering does anyone one know a way to get an element's/widget's coordinates directly from the IDE? Is there an add-on or some option that already exists? Because at the moment it is not providing me with enough information for each thing I click on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/), which is an Add-on of firefox.

After installation, perform following:

1. Click on Miscellaneous and select `Display Line Guides`
2. Click on `Add Horizontal Line Guide` button to add the horizontal line to get the Y Coordinate of Element and Click on `Add Vertical Line Guide` button to add Vertical line to get the X coordinate of Element
3. scroll horizontal/vertical line such that the element's position comes to the intersection of the lines.
4. Select Lines to see the coordinates just right to the `Add Vertical Line Guide` button

Comment: The problem is that this won't work to find the location of a dynamically changing element

Answer (score 0):

Almost every image editor program has such a feature. For instance, try opening any image in "The Gimp", and the coordinates you need will show up on the bottom left corner of the window.
if you take print screen of windows and paste in Paint then you also get coordinated.
see [image: here]

use assertelementheight command with locator show you actual value

```
             assertElemenrHeight | locator | 203
```

Comment: An interesting solution, but I need it to work inside of the Selenium IDE.